# Alternative to creating separate class

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

At the moment I have two classes, first one is called `"Building"` and second one is called `"Happening"`. Every building has its own name, and `ArrayList` of events `(Happening)` for one day. The class `Happening` has **start time** and **end time**. There can be many buildings and every building can have multiple events `(Happening)`. But as you see I am using two classes to get this job done. I know it is probably the best way, but I am curious if I could handle all this with only one class `(Building)` without needing the `Happening` class. I tried using `Happening` as an inner class, but it won't work for me, because my main method that gets data from `Building` also needs to know this class, because my `Building` has a method to return all its happenings as an Array. So I am wondering if there is any alternative way of doing this.

Comment: Two classes appears to be the best approach here, because each `Building` has a set of `Happening`s. Why do you wish to remove the `Happening` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not consider creating separate classes to be a bad thing. It makes your code easier to read, use and understand. While you undoubtedly could combine these into one class through the use of multi-dimensional lists/arrays or some other hack, the result would be a much less readable codebase. (Think of it as the same reason why, in database design, we try to separate things out into separate tables where we can, unless performance reasons dictate otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I thought I'd make things more simple by removing "unnecessary" classes, but I guess it would just make everything even more complicated.